# Django Admin Static Resources

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to learn how to use it. I've hit a brick wall trying to launch the admin site.

I'm working out of `/opt/django/mysite.com/proj1`

I'm just trying to use the built-in webserver, so `python manage.py runserver`

The admin page will load, but it's missing base.css and dashboard.css.

These files are located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/`

Seeing that it seems like ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX typically needs to be set, I've tried
`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/'` to no effect.

Could someone help me fix this problem?

Thanks,

Edit:
The GET requests where I'm seeing errors are
http://localhost:8000/admin/media/css/base.css
http://localhost:8000/admin/media/css/dashboard.css

Comment: `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` should be URL prefix, not the actual path. Are you using 1.3 or trunk?

Comment: Using 1.3.1. In that case, I assume that I need to link that the usr/lib/... directory somewhere in my /opt/django/mysite.com/proj1 hierarchy.

Comment: The default value in 1.3 is `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'`. Did you try that?

Comment: You can also supply the admin media path by `manage.py --adminmedia`, but again, the defaults should work.

Comment: Do you use development web server or apache? If you use apache error logs could help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your admin media files are located in the default directory. Try this:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/
```

For more information look to the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and just configured mod_wsgi with Apache. It works okay, but I'd still like advice if there is a better way to configure it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess apache processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=2
    WSGIProcessGroup apache
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/fmysite.com/proj1/apache.wsgi

    Alias /admin/media/ /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer is now obsolete for Django 1.4+ as ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is now obsolete.  For more information, see the [release notes for Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin)